# Substitute bunch of if to pattern matching

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have following if's in scala:

myList is some List[String]

```
if (myList.isEmpty) return x > 5
if x < 0 return false
if (myList.head == "+") return foo()
if (myList.head == "-") return bar()
```

Is it possible to do it with pattern matching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me this one is prettier:

```
if(x > 0) {
  myList.headOption match {
    case Some("+") => foo()
    case Some("-") => bar()
    case None => x > 5
} else false
```

But I'm not sure if this doesn't confront with logical flow (e.g. early exit when list is empty -- does it break something or not in your context?), if so, feel free to say so or downvote.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit awkward, but should work:

```
myList match {
  case Nil => x > 5
  case _ if x < 0 => false
  case "+" :: _ => foo()
  case "-" :: _ => bar()
}
```

Note that your match is not *exhaustive*.

Answer (score 3):

It is, you can match on an empty list, and also on items inside the list. If you need just a condition without matching, use `case _ if ...`:

```
def sampleFunction: Boolean =
  lst match {
    case Nil            => x > 5
    case _ if (x < 0)   => false
    case "+" :: _       => true
    case "-" :: _       => false
    case _              => true // return something if nothing matches
  }
```

Comment: You don't actually need the `case _` at the end; just leave it off if you know it won't get used (and you want to get a runtime exception if something crazy happens).  And you *definitely* wouldn't want to have `Any` as your return type, since there's pretty much nothing you can do with that later.

Comment: @dhg I added the last case so that it mimics the behavior of the quiestion - do nothing when nothing matches. And yes, returning `Any` has no sense, I used it just as an example (I'll better change it).

Comment: I get what you're saying now; makes sense.  But I like your edit to suggest a better approach.